# Changing routes to plural Sailsjs 0.10

Tags: sails.js

I am just getting started with Sailsjs 0.10 and I am really liking it so far, but I was wondering if it is possible to change the route-names to plural while leaving the model singular?
So if I run `sails generate api user` I want a user model accessible via a `users` route.
Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nevermind, just found it in `config/blueprint.js` under the setting `pluralize`.

Comment: Also documented in the beta docs under [blueprints config](http://beta.sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/Configuration/Blueprints.html).